# Get datatype of column in datatable

Tags: c#, datatable

I am trying to get dataType of datatable, code is

```
 for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
 {
       columntypes[j] = dt.Columns[j].GetType().Name;//dt.Rows[0][j].GetType().Name;
 }
```

checked `dt.Rows[0][j].GetType().Name;`  works fine.But In case of empty datatable it throws a error,So i tried with `dt.Columns[j].GetType().Name;` but it doesnt give proper solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
if(dt!=null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Columns.Count; j++)
     {
           columntypes[j] = dt.Columns[j].DataType.Name.ToString();
     } 
}
```

ie, you need to use the [DataType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The DataTable.Columns property is a DataColumnCollection, which can be indexed by column name to get a DataColumn, which has a DataType property.
or You may do :

```
SqlCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand(); 
cmd.CommandText = "SET FMTONLY ON; select column from table; SET FMTONLY OFF"; 
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
SqlDbType type = (SqlDbType)(int)reader.GetSchemaTable().Rows[0] ["ProviderType"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this also:

```
 int j=0;
 foreach (DataColumn dc in DT.Columns)
    {
       columntypes[j++] = dc.DataType.Name.ToString();  
    }
```